# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in one machine, but not the other one

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, sslhandshakeexception

I am having

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
```

exception on a remote machine that I have deployed my application but not getting this error on my local machine.

I know this error is about expiration of SSL certificates. I have dowloaded the new certificate of the certificate owner, imported it to the keystore of my remote machine, but still getting this error.

The strange thing in this situation is that I have not done import certificate action on my local computer.

So how can verification of a certificate give expire date error on one machine, and not on another machine?

Comment: Questioning the obvious: Have you checked to make sure the time is set correctly on the machine getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to catch the thrown `CertPathValidatorException` and use it's method `getCertPath()` for retrieving the CertPath and the certificates that cause the problem.

You should check first if the certificates are different between both machines.

If you can't catch the Exception, run your program in debug mode and add an breakpoint on the `CertPathValidatorException`. If it fires look at the contained certificates and compare them manually.

Comment: great answer! I'll check that asap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your client is checking the expiration dates on all certs being used for your ssl connection, this is an indication that either the cert or one of the certs in its chain has expired. It could also be that the date on your computer (or server) is wrong too, causion the cert to appear not to be expired when it is.

http://community.hpe.com/t5/Service-Manager-Service-Center/Urgent-Help-ValidatorException-PKIX-path-validation-failed-java/td-p/5937029

Check also if any certificates of the ssl chain is really expired or not.